# HQL JOIN only works for one set

Tags: hibernate

I have a very simple setup with SpringBoot and Hibernate, and I stumbled over a problem that seems weird to me.

I have these entities:

```java
@Entity
public class Player {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String name;
    private Color color;

    // getters & setters
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Game {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "GameCrewMembers")
    private Set<Player> crewMembers;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "GameImpostors")
    private Set<Player> impostors;
    private boolean crewWon;

    // getters & setters

}
```

Generated like this:

```java
Random rnd = new Random(314159);
List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>(personRepository.saveAll(IntStream.range(0, 100).mapToObj(i -> createPlayer(rnd)).collect(Collectors.toList())));
gameRepository.saveAll(IntStream.range(0, 50).mapToObj(i -> createGame(rnd, players)).collect(Collectors.toList()));

private Player createPlayer(Random rnd) {
    return new Player().color(Color.values()[rnd.nextInt(Color.values().length)])
            .name(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
}

private Game createGame(Random rnd, List<Player> players) {
    Game game = new Game().crewMembers(new HashSet<>()).impostors(new HashSet<>());
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
        game.getImpostors().add(players.get(rnd.nextInt(players.size())));
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
        game.getCrewMembers().add(players.get(rnd.nextInt(players.size())));
    return game;
}
```

I want to execute this HQL query:

```sql
SELECT new com.example.application.data.entity.PlayerInfo(p.name, p.color, 1, 2) FROM Game g INNER JOIN g.crewMembers as p
```

It does not work, the resulting collection is empty. How ever these queries works fine:

```sql
// replacing the crewMembers with impostors 
SELECT new com.example.application.data.entity.PlayerInfo(p.name, p.color, 1, 2) FROM Game g INNER JOIN g.impostors as p

// not using a value
SELECT p FROM Game g INNER JOIN g.crewMembers as p

// both of the above
SELECT p FROM Game g INNER JOIN g.impostors as p
```

`hibernate.show_sql` shows that the SQL query is created correctly (IMHO):

```sql
/* INNER JOIN g.crewMembers */ 
    select
        player2_.name as col_0_0_,
        player2_.color as col_1_0_,
        1 as col_2_0_,
        2 as col_3_0_ 
    from
        game game0_ 
    inner join
        game_crew_members crewmember1_ 
            on game0_.id=crewmember1_.game_id 
    inner join
        player player2_ 
            on crewmember1_.crew_members_id=player2_.id
            


/* INNER JOIN g.impostors */ 
    select
        player2_.name as col_0_0_,
        player2_.color as col_1_0_,
        1 as col_2_0_,
        2 as col_3_0_ 
    from
        game game0_ 
    inner join
        game_impostors impostors1_ 
            on game0_.id=impostors1_.game_id 
    inner join
        player player2_ 
            on impostors1_.impostors_id=player2_.id
```

(For `SELECT p` only the columns of the query get changed.)

I assume it has something to do with how Hibernate fetches collections, but I'm not sure how to move forward from this.

Why does the query return an empty collection for this specific INNER JOIN?

Comment: Try to enable sql traces `hibernate.show_sql`, `hibernate.format_sql` , `hibernate.use_sql_comments` and see what sql is generated

Comment: @SternK I added the queries to the question. They look correct to me. Especially between the working and non-working "crewMembers" query, only the columns are different.

Comment: So, maybe it happened just because you do not have in the table `game_crew_members` rows with `game_id` that matched to the `game.id`?

Comment: @SternK But then `SELECT p` would return an empty list, too. Just replacing `new com.example.application.data.entity.PlayerInfo(..)` with `p` makes it work.

Comment: @SternK And everywhere else the `Game` entity has 2 `impostors` and 8 `crewMembers`, that's a fix value for my generated dummy data.

Comment: What hibernate version and hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: Could you please also provide a minimal data set to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @SternK I did, but now I think it might not have anything to do with Hibernate at all. For some reason `System.out.println` prints an empty string for the resulting list (which I interpreted as empty list). But printing the list's size prints an actual reasonable integer. Somehow I broke the console?